Is it possible to avoid the ..runtimeconfig.json files and run with the current version of .NET Core 8.0 installed on the operating system?
I never intend to redistribute the entire runtime in each executable either by compressing it or trimming it. I also don't want to offer any kind of unnecessary ability to edit any type of Json file for any task.
I only intend to compile my managed code as a simple EXE and some modular DLLs and redistribute the DLLs and their dependencies in folders organized for example:
./Modules (My libraries)
./Thirdparty (Third party libraries)
./libs (other unmanaged libraries)

as I had been doing with the .net Framework and avoiding all types of nuget packages.
Having solved path issues and if necessary using
var currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
currentDomain.AssemblyResolve += currentDomain_AssemblyResolver;
currentDomain.AssemblyLoad += currentDomain_AssemblyLoad;

which works wonderfully.
Or is it possible to embed the Json files (so loved by some) within the executable and libraries at compilation time, but not have to embed the entire runtime in my binaries?
When I "Publish" with:
<DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
<PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
<PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>

I get an executable acceptable for modern times of 174Kb bloatware, taking into account that it is a few lines of code.
But when I run it I have these results:

A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet'.
Failed to run as a self-contained app.


The application was run as a self-contained app because C:\Seba\Release\net8.0\win-x64\publish\TestApp.runtimeconfig.json was not found.

If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the C:\Seba\net8.0\win-x64\publish\TestApp.runtimeconfig.json file and specify the appropriate framework.


And of course the TestApp.runtimeconfig.json file was obviously never generated.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3569#issuecomment-919471228
